# Returning meteor call method

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

my first time with Meteor today :)

I made a simple form that makes a POST request to the Ruby API to return an auth_code

`Meteor.call("serverEx", emailInput, passwordInput)` works great and shows an successful return in the Meteor server.

So my problem is, I am trying to return that auth_code into a variable in the meteor client

`console.log(finalVar)` is not working, shows undefined.

Any ideas? Having a feeling, I missed out something really basic.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.templateLogin.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {

      var emailInput = event.target.email.value;
      var passwordInput = event.target.password.value;

      var finalVar = Meteor.call("serverEx", emailInput, passwordInput);

      console.log(finalVar);

      return false;
    }
  });

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });

  /////////////////////
  // METHODS
  /////////////////////
  Meteor.methods({

    "serverEx" : function(a, b) {

       var httpMethod = "POST";
       var httpUrl = "http://xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/signin";

       HTTP.call(httpMethod, httpUrl, {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', params: {
         email: a,
         password: b
       }}, function (error, result) {
         if (result.statusCode === 200) {
             console.log("Success, the authcode is " + result.data.auth_token);
             return result.data.auth_token;
         }
         if (result.statusCode === 401) {
           console.log("Login failed, invalided email or password");
         }
      });
    }

  });

}
```

Comment: did you make it work?

Comment: I have tried the callback exactly like below, still returning undefined.

Comment: Looks like I have to delay the method call until I get full respond from the form submission? Something like wrapAsync but I cant figure out how to wrap it? Any advice

Comment: oh, also the "serverEx" method doesn't actually return anything. Try storing the result of your server-side HTTP call in a variable and return that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the callback option maybe.

```
 var finalVar;
     Meteor.call("serverEx", emailInput, passwordInput,function(err,result){
         if(!err){
              finalVar = result;
          }
      });      
          console.log(finalVar);
```

Comment: ah you beat me to it!

Comment: @RamsayLanier ahah =p

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are running into is synchronization. Typically, I would make the method call like this using the Meteor.call callback function:

```
Meteor.call("serverEx", emailInput, passwordInput, function(error, result){
    if (error)
       alert(error.reason)
    else
       finalVar = result;
});
```

Also, it looks like you aren't returning anything from your server-side method. Try this.

```
"serverEx" : function(a, b) {

   var httpMethod = "POST";
   var httpUrl = "http://xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/signin";
   var httpResult;


   HTTP.call(httpMethod, httpUrl, {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', params: {
     email: a,
     password: b
   }}, function (error, result) {
     if (result.statusCode === 200) {
         console.log("Success, the authcode is " + result.data.auth_token);
         httpResult = result.data.auth_token;
     }
     if (result.statusCode === 401) {
       console.log("Login failed, invalided email or password");
     }
  });

  return httpResult;
}
```

Comment: updated my answer - if this doesn't work, try not using a callback in the HTTP.call on the server-side and directly setting httpResult to the result of the call.

Comment: The only problem is, the client returns the value before the server could complete the response. If I tried the callback in the http.call, where must I put the function?

Comment: nice! this is actually super useful to know